# New hat doesn't update for already sent messages in chat

Tags: bug, chat, winter-bash-2016

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open chat and send a message.
2. Change hat.
3. Wait while chat avatar in the left bottom is updated.
4. Send another message.

> [image: chat]

If I do manual page refresh all icons become as a new one.

Comment: Sounds like it's working just fine... Why should it recheck the already-loaded avatars?

Comment: @Catija main avatar is also already-loaded. Does this mean that it is not necessary to update it after changing hats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a bug.  If you change your gravatar (no hats involved) while in a chat room, eventually your gravatar at the bottom will update and new messages will use it, but old ones are not updated.  Chat loads the image once at posting time and then never touches it again; I assume this is for performance reasons.

If you reload the page, everything updates (as you noted).